How to save matrix with many columns to SQLite database in Julia
As the question says I am trying to save a large matrix to an SQLite database in Julia. The matrix has 500 rows and 1000 columns.
When I try to save the matrix it hangs up and doesn't finish. However, I realized that I can easily save a matrix of dimensions 50000X10, which would have the same number of cells.

Is there anyway to more optimally save a matrix with many columns to an SQLite database?

I could just save the relevant CartesianIndices, but I would rather save a matrix.

Why does the number of columns affect run time so much more than the number of rows? Does this have something to do with the way SQLite works?

Here is some sample code that illustrates how much slower having extra columns is:
#test sql set 
using SQLite
using DataFrames
using Tables

db1 = SQLite.DB()#to memory

@time SQLite.load!(Tables.table(zeros(5000, 10)), db1)
@time SQLite.load!(Tables.table(zeros(500, 100)), db1)

OUTPUT:

1.237796 seconds (2.10 M allocations: 128.612 MiB, 3.90% gc time, 97.92% compilation time)

6.039620 seconds (1.29 M allocations: 80.599 MiB, 0.25% gc time, 99.86% compilation time)

We can see that the difference between 5000x10 and 500x100 is that the latter case is about 5x slower.
Thank you for your help.

The difference is all in compilation time.  Try it twice to skip compilation:
@time SQLite.load!(Tables.table(zeros(5000, 10)), db1)
@time SQLite.load!(Tables.table(zeros(500, 100)), db1)
@time SQLite.load!(Tables.table(zeros(5000, 10)), db1)
@time SQLite.load!(Tables.table(zeros(500, 100)), db1)

which prints
  0.524541 seconds (2.09 M allocations: 128.564 MiB, 6.16% gc time, 99.20% compilation time)
  2.375439 seconds (1.29 M allocations: 80.602 MiB, 0.29% gc time, 99.85% compilation time)
  0.003520 seconds (179.79 k allocations: 3.594 MiB)
  0.002945 seconds (154.17 k allocations: 2.857 MiB)

Note using BenchmarkTools.jl's @btime is better for timimg, since it compiles first and does an average of multiple runs.
I do not know why one compiles faster, but suspect one does something 100 times and the other 10 times in some compilation loop.

Unfortunately, for a table with 1000 columns. It would never finish compiling in order for me to have the opportunity to run the command again. Do you know of a work around so I can avoid splitting the matrix into pieces? Thanks

This is a problem with setting up tables in general, since they require a string as a column name for every column, and is not Julia specific afaik. If there is a way to work with the transpose (rows <==> columns) of your project this might result in better times of creating and manipulating your data.

Unfortunately, the output of the function I am writing could potentially be an even larger square matrix. It seems that the best option will be to convert the matrix to a table with 2 columns. The first is a Tuple of the coordinates, and the second is the value at that coordinate. I was trying to avoid doing this. Thank you for your help.
